# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

i get this error when i want add comment on my posts after relationship

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Posts_ID' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `Comment` (`Comment`, `posts_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (dwa, , 2018-02-03 16:47:58, 2018-02-03 16:47:58))

Route :

```
Route::get('/showpost/{showpost}/create/comment', function($ID) {
    $showpost = Posts::find($ID);
    return view('createcomment', compact('showpost'));
});

Route::post('/showpost/{showpost}/create/comment', 'PostController@storecm');
```

Controller :

```
public function storecm(Posts $showpost, Request $request)
{
    $showpost->Comment()->create($request->all());
}
```

View :

```
<form action="{{ action('PostController@storecm', $showpost->ID) }}" method="post">

    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <label>Comment :</label>
    <input type="text" name="Comment" id="Comment">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add Comment</button>

</form>
```

Comment: A couple of questions: 

1) do you have a `comment()` relationship set up in your `Posts` model? 2) If you don't, add one. If you do, then you probably need to specify the foreign key as `posts_id` (plural) since by default it'll be assuming `post_id` (singular). Also, you may want to look at MVC naming conventions. For example, model class names are typically singular (they represent an instance of the thing). If you follow these, then your relationships will be more likely to work without modifications. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error in create comment because `$request->all()` not contain `posts_id` field ,Do below changes in your Controller :

```
public function storecm(Posts $showpost, Request $request)
{
   $comment=new Comment();
   $comment->Comment=$request->input('Comment');
   $comment->posts_id=$showpost->ID;
   $comment->save();
}
```

Comment: thanks very much but i think it's not standard way ! first insert and after update that record i think is wrong, what do u think @Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Comment model that post_id is can be change?

```
Private $fillable =[
                     ‘post_id’,
                      …..
                    ];
```

You can use

```
$comment = $request->all();
$post->comments()->save($comment);
```

Answer (score 0):

remember that use 3 parameteres when use hasMany or hasOne when getting this error

```
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'Posts_ID', 'ID');
```

like this...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the "posts_id" is present in your **MODEL** under the fillable section

E.g

protected $fillable = [‘post_id’,'xyz',....];